# socket.io can't connect to server

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io, openshift

I'm hosting my application on openshift. I am using a custom domain. And socket.io wasn't able to download the client side script so I just used the cdn instead. But now it's not able to connect to a namespace. These are the errors it is giving me on the console log

[image]

This is my client side code on the .html page to download the client side script

```
<script src="https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.3.7.js"></script>
```

and the .js index page to connect to the index namespace

```
var socket = io("http://www.loomius.com/index");
```

Here is my server side code

```
var express = require('express'); 
var app = express(); 
var http = require('http');
var io = require('socket.io')(http);
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var https = require('https');

// listening on the port

app.set('port', process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_PORT || process.env.PORT || 3002);
app.set('ip', process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_IP || "127.0.0.1");

http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port') ,app.get('ip'), function () {
    console.log("✔ Express server listening at %s:%d ", app.get('ip'),app.get('port'));
});
```

Comment: _"And socket.io wasn't able to download the client side script"_. That should have been the first hint that something wasn't right in your server setup.

Comment: I used npm install socket.io. I'm migrating the server from google compute engine to openshift. I added my server side code too.

Comment: Your server setup is incorrect. See [this documentation](http://socket.io/docs/#using-with-express-3/4) on how to get `socket.io` working with Express.

Comment: that documentation is usless, its only for localhost setups, I'm trying to run on openshift. It's a lot more complicated. I tried replacing the http in require('socket.io'(http) with app and my server isn't even starting. It's saying "Please pass a http.Server instance". When my app was running on gce and openshift simultaneously, socket.io was working fine, but it was connecting to the gce server, not to the openshift server. I'm getting all these errors when I'm trying to connect to the openshift server.

Comment: Does your code actually work on localhost to begin with?

Comment: yes, ofcourse. I've created the application a while ago, I'm getting all these errors when I tried to migrate.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95843/discussion-between-rockstar5645-and-robertklep).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First instead of

```
var socket = io("http://www.loomius.com/index");
```

use this to solve issue with a need of cdn

```
var socket = io.connect("/");
```

Then on server use this instead

```
http = http.createServer( app ).listen( process.env.PORT, process.env.IP || "0.0.0.0", function() { // or define ip and port manually   
    var io = require( 'socket.io' )( http );

    io.on('connection', function( socket ) {
        // add event listeners here
    }
});
```

Comment: Great! All I needed was the ```io.connect("/");```. As the `io.connect("http://localhost");` wasn't working. Thanks man